# Author index using Biblatex with OSCOLA style

Tags: biblatex, oscola

Using the `authoryear` style, it is possible to setup multiple indexes, including an author index, as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{oscola.bib}
@article{boyle04,
    author        = {Boyle, James},
    title         = {A Manifesto on WIPO and the Future of Intellectual Property},
    journaltitle  = {2004 Duke L \& Tech Review 0009},
    url           = {http://dltr.law.duke.edu/2004/09/08/a-manifesto-on-wipo-and-the-future-of-intellectual-property},
    urldate       = {2012-07-18},
    options       = {url=true},
}
@legislation{eggs,
    title         = {Eggs and Chicks (England) Regulations},
    date          = {2009},
    number        = {SI 2009\slash 2163},
    pagination    = {regulation},
    entrysubtype  = {secondary},
}
@jurisdiction{corfu,
    title         = {Corfu Channel Case},
    subtitle      = {UK v Albania},
    titleaddon    = {Merits},
    date          = {1949},
    reporter      = {ICJ Rep},
    pages         = {4},
    keywords      = {int},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{oscola.ist}
% Part of the OSCOLA package for biblatex: see the file
% oscola.lbx for copyright and licence information
% v 1.5 01/04/2017
delim 0 "\\space\\dotfill\\space "
delim_1 "\\space\\dotfill\\space "
delim_2 "\\space\\dotfill\\space "    
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[splitindex,nonewpage]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{csquotes,xcolor,graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}

\hypersetup{
    pdfauthor={The author},
    pdftitle={The title},
    colorlinks=true,
    pdfborder={0 0 0},
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black},  
    citecolor={green!50!black},
    urlcolor={purple!80!black}
}

\usepackage[%
style=authoryear,
indexing=cite,
backend=biber,
sorting=nyt,
maxcitenames=1, 
mincitenames=1, 
maxbibnames=999, 
minbibnames=999,
refsection=section,
doi=true,
url=true             
]{biblatex}

\indexsetup{level=\section*,toclevel=section,noclearpage} 

\makeindex[name=general,intoc=true,columns=2,options=-s oscola.ist,title={General Index}]
\makeindex[name=name,intoc=true,columns=2,options=-s oscola.ist,title={Index of Authors}]
\makeindex[name=title,intoc=true,columns=1,options=-s oscola.ist,title={Index of Titles}]
\makeindex[name=ukcases,intoc=true,columns=1,options=-s oscola.ist,title={Table of UK Cases}]
\makeindex[name=ukleg, intoc=true,columns=1,options=-s oscola.ist,title={Table of UK Legislation}]

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
    \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name]}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiven}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}
}

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[title]}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
    \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames{labelname}%
        \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\renewbibmacro*{bibindex}{%
    \ifbibindex
    {\indexnames{author}%
        \indexnames{editor}%
        \indexnames{editora}%
        \indexnames{editorb}%
        \indexnames{editorc}%
        \indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}}

\addbibresource{oscola.bib}

\begin{document}

\section{My text}

Add an entry to the general index. \index[general]{IndexEntry}\par
Add a citation to an article \cite{boyle04}. The author's name to appear in the Index of Authors.\par
Add a citation to a piece of legislation \cite{eggs}\index[ukleg]{Legislation!Eggs}, which is to appear in the Table of UK legislation.\par
Manually add a case \cite{corfu}\index[ukcases]{Case!Corfu}, which is to appear in the Table of UK cases.\par
Run pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, splitindex, pdflatex

\printbibliography[nottype=jurisdiction,nottype=legislation,nottype=legal,notsubtype=parliamentary,nottype=commentary]

\printindex[general]           % Print the general index
\printindex[name]              % Print the Index of Authors
\printindex[title]             % Print the Index of Titles
\printindex[ukleg]             % Print the Index of UK Legislation
\printindex[ukcases]           % Print the Index of UK cases

\end{document}
```

Which produces this, as required:

[image]

`OSCOLA` is the Oxford University Standard for the Citation of Legal Authorities. It is implemented for `Biblatex` using the `OSCOLA` package.

Changing the `authoryear` style on line 61 to the `oscola` style, results in the incorrectly producing the author index, as follows:

[image]

The OSCOLA standard requires the use of footnote citations, and defines the command `\footcite` for this purpose. My understanding is that the the incorrect author index will be due to incorrectly defining `\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name]}` for the `oscola` style.

Advice regarding how to create an author index for the `oscola` style would be appreciated.

A secondary question concerns the formatting of the index. I expect `makeindex` to use `oscola.ist` to produce an index with right aligned page numbers separated from the index item by `\dotfill`. However, there is no dotfill and the page numbers are `raggedright`.

The file is compiled with:
`pdflatex`, `biber`, `pdflatex`, `splitindex`,`pdflatex`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`oscola` indeed redefines `index:name` quite a bit.

You can restore the default with

```
\renewbibmacro*{index:name}[5]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:entry}{#1}{\mkbibindexname{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}}
```